# Isomorphism $\left(\mathbb{C}^{n}\setminus\{0\}\right)/\mathbb{Z}$ with $S^{1} \times S^{2n-1}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, geometry, algebraic-topology

I have to prove that there is this isomorphism:
$$\frac{\mathbb{C}^{n}{\setminus\{0\}}}{ \mathbb{Z}} \simeq S^{1} \times S^{2n-1},$$
where there is this equivalence relation in the left side:
$(w_1, \dots, w_n) \sim (z_1, \dots, z_n)$ if exists $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}$ with $|\lambda| \ge 1$ and a fixed $d \in \mathbb{N}$ such that
$$(w_1, \dots, w_n) \sim (\lambda^d z_1, \dots,\lambda^d z_n).$$

Comment: You mean homeomorphism. Also, the title does not match the actual question.

Comment: Probably you want $|\lambda| > 1$.  Certainly $\lambda$ cannot be a root of unity, or the action factors through a finite quotient of $\mathbb{Z}$ and thus cannot have compact quotient.

Comment: Moreover, $\lambda$ should be fixed once and for all. As stated, the quantifiers are messed up!

Comment: Finally, you need $d$ to be in $\mathbb Z$. Since you say that you *have to prove this*, I imagine you got the problem from somewhere... Make extra sure that you copied it correctly!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider the map $$\phi:z\in\mathbb C^n\setminus\{0\}\mapsto\Bigl(\frac{z}{|z|},\log|z|\Bigr)\in S^{2n-1}\times\mathbb R.$$

- Show that it is an homeomorphism.
- Next, define on the codomain of $\phi$ an equivalence relation $\equiv$ such that $\phi$ induces an homeomorphism from $(\mathbb C^n\setminus\{0\})/\sim$ to $(S^{2n-1}\times\mathbb R)/\equiv$.
- Figure out what $(S^{2n-1}\times\mathbb R)/\equiv$ is.

Comment: How can I define $\equiv$?